# Override Apple's UIButton Highlight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I have a button, where I set its image and its selected & highlighted state image as follows:

```
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_learn_pad"];
        self.learnMoreButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)];
        [self.learnMoreButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.learnMoreButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_learn_focus_pad"] forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected];
        [self.learnMoreButton addTarget:self action:nil forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This still overlays Apple's darker alpha on top of the image upon selection. How do I remove this effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of setImage:forState use `setBackgroundImage:forState`:

```
[self.learnMoreButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_learn_pad"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.learnMoreButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_learn_focus_pad"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: I edited the answer, this always worked for me for a button of type custom. But I also tried setImage, which also worked. I think because I use 2 statements, this works

Comment: What's the point? Are you reading the question? I need a different image, called btn_learn_focus_pad, that will display when highlighted / selected. So Normal state is DIFFERENT than highlighted selected. And I can just separate states by `|`, two statements or one does not matter.

Comment: Well, I dont't know, did you try it? I did, sorry for the copy/paste typo in the example code, and it just works for me